# Cairo-dock confiuration GUI has black background and text

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-background, cairo-dock

At some point in time after installing cairo-dock whenever I go into the configuration screen some of the background is black with black text and I can't read what it says. I tried highlighting the text with the mouse but it won't let me. I am running Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I have a screenshot but I don't seem to be able to post it here. I am using cairo-dock version 3.2.1.

[image: Cairo-Dock configuration GUI]

Answer (score 1):

Found out this had to do with my GTK themes. If I wasn't using a GTK3 theme then I would get the black background. Once I changed my theme to something else I now can see all the text. The GUI has the correct background.

Comment: I had black select boxes. It had to do with the dock background color set to black. Cairo dock has a lot of issues and inconsistencies, but it is the only reasonable dock out there. There is no other decent option out there